# нужно вернуть значение switch1 при повторном открытии программы

Tags: java, android

У меня есть ползунок (switch1) который хранит  либо Tru либо False 
Когда я закрываю программу все теряется.
Мне нужно вернуть значение switch1 при повторном открытии программы.

(Желательно не сложно ничего не понимаю.)

Comment: Вам нужно в SharedPreferences данные сохранить и оттуда же прочитать. Где-то тут на сайте была инструкция, но я её с ходу не нашёл(

Answer (score 4):

Состояние ползунка (True или False) нужно куда-нибудь сохранить: в БД, SharedPreferences, или просто в файл. Тогда при открытии приложения нужно будет восстанавливать состояние ползунка с помощью ранее сохраненной информации о нем.

Можно сделать, например, так: при каждом изменении состояния ползунка, сохранять в SharedPreferences его состояние:

```java
switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton compoundButton, final boolean isChecked) {
        context.getSharedPreferences("app_preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                .putBoolean("switch_state", isChecked)
                .apply();
    }
});
```

А затем после каждого открытия приложения восстанавливать это состояние:

```java
switch1.setChecked(context.getSharedPreferences("app_preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("switch_state", false));
```